# Parse JSON response into a data model with Swift (LinkedIn API)

Tags: ios, json, swift, linkedin-api

I am using **LinkedInSwift** to get the users data after they have authenticated their credentials. I have been able to print out my `response` which displays their data. But I am now trying to parse that data into data model.

I have a `User` class:

```
typealias JSON = [String: Any]

class User {

    var id: String?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?

    init(json: JSON) {

        guard let id = json["id"] as? String, let firstName = json["firstName"] as? String, let lastName = json["lastName"] as? String else { return }

        self.id = id
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
```

and here is may get method for LinkedIn:

```
linkedinHelper.authorizeSuccess({ (lsToken) -> Void in
            //Login success lsToken
            print("User has logged in succesfully!")

            //Check if the user user is logged in and perform and action if they are.
            if self.linkedinHelper.lsAccessToken != nil {
                self.linkedinHelper.requestURL("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name)?format=json",
                                          requestType: LinkedinSwiftRequestGet,
                                          success: { (response) -> Void in

                                            print(response)

                                            //Request success response
                }) { [unowned self] (error) -> Void in

                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    //Encounter error
                }
            } else {

            }

        }, error: { (error) -> Void in
            print("Uh oh, there was an issue.")
            //Encounter error: error.localizedDescription
        }, cancel: { () -> Void in
            print("Cancelled")
            //User Cancelled!
        })
}
```

I have looked in various places about this but it seems that the only examples and documentations stop at the `response` or requires a third-party framework to parse data. Can someone help direct me into achieving my goal please.

**Update**

Result of of printing `response`:

```
<LSResponse - data: {
    firstName = Joe;
    id = htcxTEeLk4;
    lastName = Smith;
},
```

Comment: Can you add the JSON Data you're being supplied?

Comment: @ZonilyJame Please see updated question.

Comment: You should use `response.jsonObject` instead of just `response`

Comment: Please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766253/cannot-convert-value-of-type-key-anyhashable-value-any-to-expected-argume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User {

var id: String?
var firstName: String?
var lastName: String?

init(json: JSON) {

    guard let id = json["id"] as? String, let firstName = json["firstName"] as? String, let lastName = json["lastName"] as? String else { return }

    self.id = id
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
}

linkedinHelper.authorizeSuccess({ (lsToken) -> Void in
        //Login success lsToken
        print("User has logged in succesfully!")

        //Check if the user user is logged in and perform and action if they are.
        if self.linkedinHelper.lsAccessToken != nil {
            self.linkedinHelper.requestURL("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name)?format=json",
                                      requestType: LinkedinSwiftRequestGet,
                                      success: { (response) -> Void in

                                        let user = User(json: response.jsonObject)


                                        //Request success response
            }) { [unowned self] (error) -> Void in

                print(error.localizedDescription)
                //Encounter error
            }
        } else {

        }

    }, error: { (error) -> Void in
        print("Uh oh, there was an issue.")
        //Encounter error: error.localizedDescription
    }, cancel: { () -> Void in
        print("Cancelled")
        //User Cancelled!
    })
}
```

Comment: It's giving me an error saying: `'(key: AnyHashable, value: Any)' to expected argument type 'JSON' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>')` and when I cast it as JSON like this: `let user = LinkedInData(json: response.jsonObject as! JSON)` and print `user?.firstName` I get `Optional("Joe")` it.

Comment: firstName is optional, unwrap it and the optional will vanish.

Comment: I am trying to unwrap it like this `self.textLbl.text = "Hello /\(String(describing: user?.firstName!))"` But it's not working :/

Comment: if let fName = user?.firstName {
   self.textLbl.text = fName
}